# Is it good practice to keep 2 related tables (using auto_increment PK) to have the same Max of auto_increment ID when table1 got modified?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let see this example, we have 2 interrelated tables:

```
Table1
textID - text
1      - love..
2      - men...
...

Table2
rID - textID
1   - 1
2   - 2
...
```

Note:

In Table1:

- `textID` is auto_increment primary key

In Table2:

- `rID` is auto_increment primary key & `textID` is foreign key
- The relationship is that 1 `rID` will have 1 and only 1 `textID` but 1 `textID` can have a few `rID`.

So, when table1 got modification then table2 should be updated accordingly.

Ok, here is a fictitious example. You build a very complicated system. When you modify 1 record in table1, you need to keep track of the related record in table2. To keep track, you can do like this:

**Option 1**: When you modify a record in table1, you will try to modify a related record in table 2. This could be quite hard in term of programming expecially for a very very complicated system.

**Option 2**: instead of modifying a related record in table2, you decided to delete old record in table 2 & insert new one. This is easier for you to program.

For example, suppose you are using option2, then when you modify `record 1,2,3,....,100` in table1, the table2 will look like this:

```
Table2
rID   - textID
101   - 1
102   - 2
...
200   - 100
```

This means the **Max** of auto_increment IDs in table1 is still the same (100) but the **Max** of auto_increment IDs in table2 already reached 200.

what if the user modify many times? if they do then the table2 may run out of records? we can use `BigInt` but that make the app run slower?

Note: If you spend time to program to modify records in table2 when table1 got modified then it will be very hard & thus it will be error prone. But if you just clear the old record & insert new records  into table2 then it is much easy to program & thus your program is simpler & less error prone.

**So, is it good practice to keep 2 related tables (using auto_increment PK) to have the same Max of auto_increment ID when table1 got modified?**

Comment: terrible idea. if the keys should be synchronized, then it's really one key so combine the two tables into one table. otherwise, they are separate tables - leave them like that.

Comment: The relationship is that 1 `rID` will have 1 and only 1 `textID` but 1 `textID` can have a few `rID`.

Comment: Big deal. So you have a one-to-many relationship between table1 and table2. Define a foreign key in table2. Move on.

Comment: what "Move on" means ? so should I (delete & insert) or update the records in table2 when records in table 1 got modified? Delete & insert is easier to program but update is pretty hard.

Comment: "Move on" means do something else (productive). You should never update the key. It's a key - don't use it for anything other than permanently identifying the row. Google "surrogate key" - that's what you've got, and it's the usual approach.

Comment: maybe u misunderstood, I don't change the key from 1 to 11 or any other number. The key is fixed. We only change the text of the record of that key. Ex, in table1, ID=1 & if I change the text from "love"  to "unlove" then I need to update the table 2 accordingly.